# Upload files to Firebase Storage using Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, gcloud, firebase-storage

I'm trying to understand how to upload files in Firebase Storage, using Node.js. My first try was to use the Firebase library:

```
"use strict";

var firebase = require('firebase');

var config = {
    apiKey: "AIz...kBY",
    authDomain: "em....firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://em....firebaseio.com",
    storageBucket: "em....appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "95...6"
};

firebase.initializeApp(config);

// Error: firebase.storage is undefined, so not a function
var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref();

var uploadTask = storageRef.child('images/octofez.png').put(file);

// Register three observers:
// 1. 'state_changed' observer, called any time the state changes
// 2. Error observer, called on failure
// 3. Completion observer, called on successful completion
uploadTask.on('state_changed', function(snapshot){
    ...
}, function(error) {
    console.error("Something nasty happened", error);
}, function() {
  var downloadURL = uploadTask.snapshot.downloadURL;
  console.log("Done. Enjoy.", downloadURL);
});
```

But it turns out that Firebase cannot upload files from the server side, as it clearly states in the docs:

> Firebase Storage is not included in the server side Firebase npm module. Instead, you can use the gcloud Node.js client.
>
> `$ npm install --save gcloud`
>
> In your code, you can access your Storage bucket using:
>
> ```
> var gcloud = require('gcloud')({ ... }); var gcs = gcloud.storage();
> var bucket = gcs.bucket('<your-firebase-storage-bucket>');
> ```

- Can we use `gcloud` without having an account on Google Cloud Platform? How?
- If not, how come that uploading files to Firebase Storage from the client side is possible?
- Can't we just create a library that makes the same requests from the server side?
- How is Firebase Storage connected with Google Cloud Platform at all? Why Firebase allows us to upload images only from the client side?

---

My second try was to use the `gcloud` library, like mentioned in the docs:

```
var gcloud = require("gcloud");

// The following environment variables are set by app.yaml when running on GAE,
// but will need to be manually set when running locally.
// The storage client is used to communicate with Google Cloud Storage
var storage = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: "em...",
  keyFilename: 'auth.json'
});

storage.createBucket('octocats', function(err, bucket) {

    // Error: 403, accountDisabled
    // The account for the specified project has been disabled.

    // Create a new blob in the bucket and upload the file data.
    var blob = bucket.file("octofez.png");
    var blobStream = blob.createWriteStream();

    blobStream.on('error', function (err) {
        console.error(err);
    });

    blobStream.on('finish', function () {
        var publicUrl = `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucket.name}/${blob.name}`;
        console.log(publicUrl);
    });

    fs.createReadStream("octofez.png").pipe(blobStream);
});
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When using the firebase library on a server you would typically authorize [using a service account](https://firebase.google.com/docs/server/setup) as this will give you admin access to the Realtime database for instance. You can use the same Service Account's credentials file to [authorize gcloud](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gcloud#elsewhere).

By the way: A Firebase project is essentially also a Google Cloud Platform project, you can access your Firebase project on both https://console.firebase.google.com and https://console.cloud.google.com and https://console.developers.google.com
You can see your Project ID on the [Firebase Console > Project Settings](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/settings/general/) or in the [Cloud Console Dashboard](https://console.cloud.google.com/home/dashboard?project=_)

When using the gcloud SDK make sure that you use the (already existing) same bucket that Firebase Storage is using. You can find the bucket name in the Firebase web `config` object or in the Firebase Storage tab. Basically your code should start like this:

```
var gcloud = require('gcloud');

var storage = gcloud.storage({
  projectId: '<projectID>',
  keyFilename: 'service-account-credentials.json'
});

var bucket = storage.bucket('<projectID>.appspot.com');

...
```

Comment: That was really helpful, but still, the root problem is still there: I cannot upload stuff using `gcloud` (for instance, creating a bucket) because, according to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23136508/1420197), I didn't enable billing. Again, why accessing Storage via `gcloud` would require billing while accessing it via client side firebase would not? Thanks!

Comment: I added another snippet to my question.

Comment: It seems you might need to enable billing this is true. I'll report to the team internally. There are always debates whether if we should create a Firebase specific Server SDK for Storage and for now the consensus is "no". For the billing issue: as a workaround you can enable billing and set a budget with a limit of Zero USD to avoid getting billed anything. The API itself should be free to use and the bucket that Firebase Storage uses has a free quota so things should be working.

Comment: Looks like an issue to me—to enable billing, I need a billing account. For a billing account I need to sign up on Google Cloud Platform and to sign up there I need a business. All these just to upload something in Firebase Storage from the server side. I'm curious what they will say. Thanks!

Comment: Can't you create the billing account as an individual? In my case I can (I am in Switzerland). If not could you tell me which country you are located in? (This will help for the internal discussions)

Comment: I'm in Romania—after accepting the terms, this page is opened `https://console.cloud.google.com/freetrial` where clearly states: *This service can only be used for business or commercial reasons. You are responsible for assessing and reporting VAT.*. At least I don't see any other way to skip that. While the VAT id is optional, the business name is mandatory.

Comment: What makes me think at is: why we cannot do the same POST (or PUT etc) request from the server, in the same way like we do it on the client? Probably we can. Would I break the rules if I made one? :-)

Comment: OK I see that for Romania. For Switzerland and USA there is an option to sign up as an individual, thanks. You can always try to send your own requests but just be aware since these are undocumented they could change in non-backward compatible ways (although that's unlikely IMO).

Comment: I see—probably it's better to wait for feedback from you. I wrote you an email. Thanks!

Comment: Hey Ionica, I initially missed that you are trying to create a new bucket with `storage.createBucket('octocats', function(err, bucket) {` you can't do that without billing (only the Firebase/App Engine bucket are free, other buckets are not). Can you try not creating a bucket and instead using the already created Firebase bucket? The bucket name is in your Firebase config `storageBucket: "em....appspot.com",`

Comment: Basically instead you should use this: `var bucket = storage.bucket('em....appspot.com')`

Comment: Yay! It works. I posted [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-nodejs/issues/6#issuecomment-251478326) my code. You can include it in the post if you like. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please take a look [at this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/40177087/1420197)?

Comment: So how do I upload a nodejs app to Firebase?  Because I just logged into my Firebase account which I havent used in a while and noticed that there are links to 2 recently created Google Actions projects (which is precisely what I want to move from Heroku to Firebase) that have been added automatically.  But the link takes me to the console.  Can I connect deploy it from my github or upload it from a terminal? Does anyone have a video link tutorial for this?

Comment: Where is `service-account-credentials.json`?

Comment: `gloud` is depreicated now

Answer (score 19):

Firebase Storage is now supported by the admin SDK with NodeJS:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.storage

```
// Get the Storage service for the default app
var defaultStorage = firebaseAdmin.storage();
var bucket = defaultStorage.bucket('bucketName');
...
```

Comment: When I try this, I get `TypeError: defaultStorage is not a function`. With the latest `firebase-admin` npm library.

Comment: `var bucket = firebaseAdmin.storage().bucket('bucketName');` - that does the trick, following this as a guide: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start#use_a_custom_firebase_app

Comment: What comes after `bucket()` to get a ref()? These seem to work: bucket.ref() or bucket.child('path')

Answer (score 13):

Firebase Admin SDK allows you to directly access your Google Cloud Storage.

For more detail visit [Introduction to the Admin Cloud Storage API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start)

```
var admin = require("firebase-admin");
var serviceAccount = require("path/to/serviceAccountKey.json");

admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: "<BUCKET_NAME>.appspot.com"
});

var bucket = admin.storage().bucket();

bucket.upload('Local file to upload, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt')
```

Comment: How do i download a file on Storage ?

Comment: By using the method [getDownloadURL()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference.html#getdownloadurl)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But can you please share an example of how to use the getDownloadURL() ? Thanks again.

Comment: `const destFilename = 'Local destination for file, e.g. ./local/path/to/file.txt';`


`const options = {`
    `// The path to which the file should be downloaded, e.g. "./file.txt"`
    `destination: destFilename,`
  `};`
  `bucket.file('Remote file to download, e.g. file.txt').download(options)`

ref [Downloading objects](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/downloading-objects)

Comment: @Learn2Code the above code will download the file from storage to local.

Answer (score 8):

I hope It will useful for you. I uploaded one file from locally and then I added access Token using UUID after that I uploaded into firebase storage.There after I am generating download url. If we hitting that generate url it will automatically downloaded a file.

```
    const keyFilename="./xxxxx.json"; //replace this with api key file
    const projectId = "xxxx" //replace with your project id
    const bucketName = "xx.xx.appspot.com"; //Add your bucket name
    var mime=require('mime-types');
    const { Storage } = require('@google-cloud/storage');
    const uuidv1 = require('uuid/v1');//this for unique id generation

   const gcs = new Storage({
    projectId: projectId,
    keyFilename: './xxxx.json'
     });
    const bucket = gcs.bucket(bucketName);

    const filePath = "./sample.odp";
    const remotePath = "/test/sample.odp";
    const fileMime = mime.lookup(filePath);

//we need to pass those parameters for this function
    var upload = (filePath, remoteFile, fileMime) => {

      let uuid = uuidv1();

      return bucket.upload(filePath, {
            destination: remoteFile,
            uploadType: "media",
            metadata: {
              contentType: fileMime,
              metadata: {
                firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid
              }
            }
          })
          .then((data) => {

              let file = data[0];

              return Promise.resolve("https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/" + bucket.name + "/o/" + encodeURIComponent(file.name) + "?alt=media&token=" + uuid);
          });
    }
//This function is for generation download url    
 upload(filePath, remotePath, fileMime).then( downloadURL => {
        console.log(downloadURL);

      });
```

Answer (score 4):

Note that gcloud is deprecated, use google-cloud instead. 
You can find SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE_PATH at project settings->Service Accounts.

```
var storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

var gcs = storage({
    projectId: PROJECT_ID,
    keyFilename: SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY_FILE_PATH
  });

// Reference an existing bucket.
var bucket = gcs.bucket(PROJECT_ID + '.appspot.com');

...
```

Comment: How would I download an image after I do the setup as you described?

Comment: TypeError: storage is not a function. Which version of @google-cloud/storage you were using? Mine is 4.5.0

Answer (score 2):

Or you could simply polyfill `XmlHttpRequest` like so -

```
const XMLHttpRequest = require("xhr2");
global.XMLHttpRequest = XMLHttpRequest
```

and import

```
require('firebase/storage');
```

That's it. All `firebase.storage()` methods should now work.

Comment: TypeError: firebase.storage is not a function

Answer (score -1):

**I have implemented the API to upload the file on the firebase storage:**

```
const fs = require('firebase-admin');
const app = require('express')();
const serviceAccount = require('./serviceAccountKey_DEV.json');

fs.initializeApp({
    credential: fs.credential.cert(serviceAccount),
    storageBucket: `${serviceAccount.project_id}.appspot.com`
});

// Upload the file on firebase storage
app.get("/upload-on-firebase", async (req, res, next) => {
    var bucket = fs.storage().bucket();
    const result = await bucket.upload('data.json');
    console.log('result :', result);
    return res.send(result);
});
```

**Call API to upload:**

```
curl --location --request GET 'http://localhost:3000/upload-on-firebase'
```

**Response:**

```
[
    {
        "_events": {},
        "_eventsCount": 0,
        "metadata": {
            "kind": "storage#object",
            "id": "project_id.appspot.com/data.json/1678222222",
            "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/storage/v1/b/project_id.appspot.com/o/data.json",
            "mediaLink": "https://storage.googleapis.com/download/storage/v1/b/project_id.appspot.com/o/data.json",
            "name": "data.json",
            "bucket": "project_id.appspot.com",
            "generation": "16787922222222",
            "metageneration": "1",
            "contentType": "application/json",
            "storageClass": "STANDARD",
            ....
            ....
            ....
        },
        "baseUrl": "/o",
    }
]
```