# How to upload files to the GCloud in Node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, multer

**WHAT I LOOKED AT:**

- [Integrate with Google Cloud Platform](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/gcp-integration)
- [Upload files to Firebase Storage using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848132/upload-files-to-firebase-storage-using-node-js)

---

**THOUGHTS:**

I currently store the images locally and store the image paths in the Firebase realtime database. I would like to store the images in the GCloud (to reduce costs).

---

**QUESTION:**

HOW SHOULD I MODIFY MY CURRENT CODE TO UPLOAD TO THE GCLOUD ?

---

**CURRENT CODE:**

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var flash = require("connect-flash");

var firebase = require("firebase");

var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({dest:"./public/images/uploads/", limits: {fileSize: 250000}}).single("image");


router.get("/", function(req, res, next){

    if (firebase.auth().currentUser == null) {
        global.page_name = "login";
        res.render("users/login");
    }
    else {
        global.page_name = "upload";
        res.render("upload");
    }
});

router.post("/", function(req, res, next){
    upload(req,res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash("error_msg", "File too large. Max Size: 250KB");
            res.redirect("/upload"); 
            return
        }


        var title = req.body.title;
        var section = req.body.section;

        // Validation
        req.checkBody('title', 'Title is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('title', 'Title is too long, max: 50 charachters !').len(0,50);
        req.checkBody('section', 'Section is required').notEmpty();

        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors){
            res.render('upload', {
                errors: errors
            });
        }
        else {

            if (req.file){

                console.log("Uploading file...");
                var image = req.file.filename;
                var section = req.body.section.toLowerCase();

                var IDref = firebase.database().ref("posts/"+section+"/lastID");

                IDref.once("value", function(IDsnapshot){
                    var number = IDsnapshot.val();
                    var postRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/"+section).push();
                    var UID = postRef.key;
                    var post = {
                        title: req.body.title,
                        section: req.body.section,
                        image: image,
                        author: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
                        section:  section,
                        upvotes: 0,
                        downvotes: 0,
                        id: number + 1,
                        key: UID
                    }

                    IDref.set(post.id);

                    postRef.set(post);

                    var authoredPost = {
                        title: req.body.title,
                        section: section,
                    }

                    var userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/"+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid.toString()+"/posts/"+UID.toString());
                    userRef.set(authoredPost);

                });

                req.flash("success_msg", "Post Created");
                res.redirect("/upload"); 
            }
            else {
                console.log("No file uploaded");
                req.flash("error_msg", "Image is required");
                res.redirect("/upload");
            }
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: This is a really great question. Thanks for listing the resources you've seen. Have you tried to follow this one? If you have, what issues did you have? https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-storage

Answer (score 6, accepted):

i think its better to use firebase.storage in web or app to upload directly to the GCloud but you can use this code to solve your problem

```
var express = require("express");
var router = express.Router();
var flash = require("connect-flash");

var fs = require('fs');
var firebase = require("firebase");
var gcloud = require('google-cloud');

var multer = require("multer");
var upload = multer({dest:"./public/images/uploads/", limits: {fileSize: 250000}}).single("image");


// Enable Storage
var gcs = gcloud.storage({
    projectId: 'grape-spaceship-123',
    keyFilename: '/path/to/keyfile.json'
});

// Reference an existing bucket.
var bucket = gcs.bucket('my-existing-bucket');

router.get("/", function(req, res, next){
    if (firebase.auth().currentUser == null) {
        global.page_name = "login";
        res.render("users/login");
    }
    else {
        global.page_name = "upload";
        res.render("upload");
    }
});

router.post("/", function(req, res, next){
    upload(req,res, function (err) {
        if (err) {
            req.flash("error_msg", "File too large. Max Size: 250KB");
            res.redirect("/upload");
            return
        }


        var title = req.body.title;
        var section = req.body.section;

        // Validation
        req.checkBody('title', 'Title is required').notEmpty();
        req.checkBody('title', 'Title is too long, max: 50 charachters !').len(0,50);
        req.checkBody('section', 'Section is required').notEmpty();

        var errors = req.validationErrors();

        if(errors){
            res.render('upload', {
                errors: errors
            });
        }
        else {

            if (req.file){


                console.log("image saved successfully in local");

                //upload to the GCloud
                bucket.upload(req.file.filename, function(err, file) {
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("image saved successfully in GCloud");


                        //remove local image
                        fs.unlink(req.file.filename, (err) => {
                            if (err) throw err;
                                console.log('successfully deleted /tmp/hello');
                        });


                        //store image name in firebase
                        var image = file.name;//may be another key hold the image name.
                        var section = req.body.section.toLowerCase();

                        var IDref = firebase.database().ref("posts/"+section+"/lastID");

                        IDref.once("value", function(IDsnapshot){
                            var number = IDsnapshot.val();
                            var postRef = firebase.database().ref("posts/"+section).push();
                            var UID = postRef.key;
                            var post = {
                                title: req.body.title,
                                section: req.body.section,
                                image: image,
                                author: firebase.auth().currentUser.uid,
                                section:  section,
                                upvotes: 0,
                                downvotes: 0,
                                id: number + 1,
                                key: UID
                            }

                            IDref.set(post.id);

                            postRef.set(post);

                            var authoredPost = {
                                title: req.body.title,
                                section: section,
                            }

                            var userRef = firebase.database().ref("users/"+firebase.auth().currentUser.uid.toString()+"/posts/"+UID.toString());
                            userRef.set(authoredPost);

                        });

                        req.flash("success_msg", "Post Created");
                        res.redirect("/upload");

                    }
                });




            }
            else {
                console.log("No file uploaded");
                req.flash("error_msg", "Image is required");
                res.redirect("/upload");
            }
        }
    });
});

module.exports = router;
```

Comment: I can't use firebase.storage because the SDK is not working with Node.js and Firebase has no plans to add it for Node.js :( (I will try your code in the next 24hours)

Comment: For reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848132/upload-files-to-firebase-storage-using-node-js

Comment: do you use this code and routing by another node js program or a client like web app or android app or ios app?

Comment: definitely you have a client because you don't need upload when you call it by another node js program, and in a client you can use firebase.storage