# Can I use firebase storage from admin?

Tags: firebase, admin, firebase-storage

I have used firebase database from a java program ran on my computer. It works perfectly, I'm now looking to do the same with firebase storage as I want to add images. It doesn't seem possible as it's not mentioned in the documentation (Firebase storage only has ios, android and web whereas firebase database has those plus admin) however it seems like an obvious feature to have. Does anyone know if it's possible to access firebase storage from the admin sdk and if so how?

Comment: Firebase Storage has been renamed Cloud Storage for Firebase, to make it clearer that Firebase really "just" provides a client-side SDK and associated security model to access Google Cloud Storage. To access Cloud Storage from Cloud Functions (or any other Node.js program), you use the `gcloud` node module. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39848132/upload-files-to-firebase-storage-using-node-js

Comment: Woops... I might have picked a wrong duplicate to link here. If you're trying to access Cloud Storage from a Java program, see https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/xml-api/java-samples

Comment: Ah much appreciated. Understand it all now. In the firebase docs it literally says 'On the server, you can use Google Cloud Storage, to access the same files.'

Comment: I was looking for that quote, good to hear that *you* found it. :-)