# Access Firebase Storage with Node.js as a Firebase user

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I want to verify that [Firebase Storage rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start) are working as expected with automated Node.js tests.

One can access Firebase Storage buckets with the Firebase Admin API or a service account, as indicated in [Upload files to Firebase Storage using Node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39848132/19212).

The problem is that using the Admin API or a service account circumvents the storage rules.

There is no apparent way to access Firebase Storage as a given Firebase user, as the [Firebase Node.js API](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/) does not include a `firebase.storage` function.

In short, how can one access Firebase Storage from Node.js as a given Firebase user/uid?

Comment: The doc of the node.js API to access Storage is here: https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/docs/reference/storage/1.7.x. If I am not mistaking you can authenticate through https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started#auth-cloud-implicit-nodejs. Note also the acl class that may help you with your tests.

Comment: Thanks @RenaudTarnec, that's helpful.  An ideal answer would indicate how to get the OAuth credentials for a Firebase user for authentication as that user per https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/end-user.

Comment: I do agree... Since I was not sure that I could exactly/precisely describe how to authenticate I wrote a comment and not an answer :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is currently no way to accomplish what you want.

There *is* a [`storage()` service in the Firebase Admin SDK for Node.js](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/admin/start), but as you've discovered this gives full administrative access to your bucket.

While the [Admin SDK for the Realtime Database can be initialized to access the database as a specific user](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/admin/start#authenticate-with-limited-privileges), this feature is not available for the Storage service.

What you want to do sounds quite reasonable though, so I recommend that you [file a feature request](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/bugs-features/). In the meantime, the best I can think of is running those unit tests in a browser, so that you can authenticate with the regular JavaScript client SDK.

Comment: Thanks Frank.  I've already filed an issue and linked to this question.  I've marked this correct (subject to further information or this feature being added to Firebase).