# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'storage' of undefined

Tags: angular, typescript, firebase

I'm uploading an image to firebase then am trying to save its download URL to `ionic storage` but it gives me this error

`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'storage' of undefined`

here is my code :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AngularFirestore, AngularFirestoreCollection } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';
import * as firebase from 'firebase';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import uuid from 'uuid/v1'; //here change 'v1' with the version you desire to use

export interface Dress {
  id?: string;
  title: string;
  description: string;
  createdAt: number;
  category: string;
  price: number;
  city: string;
  type: string;
  size: string;
  action: string;
  image_1: string;
  image_2: string;
  image_3: string;
}
export interface Category {
  name: string;
}
export interface City {
  name: string;
}
export interface Type {
  name: string;
}
export interface Size {
  name: string;
}
export interface Action {
  name: string;
}

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DressService {
  private dressCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Dress>;
  private dress: Observable<Dress[]>;
  private categoryCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Category>;
  private category: Observable<Category[]>;
  private cityCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<City>;
  private city: Observable<City[]>;
  private typeCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Type>;
  private type: Observable<Type[]>;
  private sizeCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Size>;
  private size: Observable<Size[]>;
  private actionCollection: AngularFirestoreCollection<Action>;
  private action: Observable<Action[]>;
  id = uuid();

  constructor(db: AngularFirestore,
              public storage: Storage,
  ) {
    this.dressCollection = db.collection<Dress>('dress');
    this.dress = this.dressCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
    this.categoryCollection = db.collection<Category>('categories');
    this.category = this.categoryCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
    this.cityCollection = db.collection<City>('cities');
    this.city = this.cityCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
    this.typeCollection = db.collection<Type>('types');
    this.type = this.typeCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
    this.sizeCollection = db.collection<Size>('sizes');
    this.size = this.sizeCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
    this.actionCollection = db.collection<Action>('actions');
    this.action = this.actionCollection.snapshotChanges().pipe(
      map(actions => {
        return actions.map(a => {
          const data = a.payload.doc.data();
          const id = a.payload.doc.id;
          return { id, ...data };
        });
      })
    );
  }
  getDresses() {
    return this.dress;
  }
  getCategories() {
    return this.category;
  }
  getTypes() {
    return this.type;
  }
  getCities() {
    return this.city;
  }
  getSizes() {
    return this.size;
  }
  getActions() {
    return this.action;
  }
  getDress(id) {
    return this.dressCollection.doc<Dress>(id).valueChanges();
  }
  updateDress(dress: Dress, id: string) {
    return this.dressCollection.doc(id).update(dress);
  }
  addDress(dress: Dress) {
    return this.dressCollection.add(dress);
  }
  removeDress(id) {
    return this.dressCollection.doc(id).delete();
  }
  uploadImage(img, numb) {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('Uploads');
    const storage = firebase.storage();
    const pathReference = storage.ref('images/' + this.id + numb + '.jpg');
    const message = img;
    pathReference.putString(message, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpg' }).then(function (snapshot) {
      console.log('Uploaded a base64url string!');
      pathReference.getDownloadURL().then(function (url) {
        console.log(url);
        console.log(typeof(url));
        if (numb === 1) {
          this.storage.set('image_1_url', url);
        }
        if (numb === 2) {
          this.storage.set('image_2_url', url);
        }
        if (numb === 3) {
          this.storage.set('image_3_url', url);
        }
      });
    });


  }
}
```

when I call the `uploadImage()` function after picking the image, it uploads and generates the URL already but it fails to save it, the error comes from this line

```
        if (numb === 1) {
          this.storage.set('image_1_url', url);
        }
```

I have the proper config for my firebase and everything works perfectly, it only fails when it comes to the `ionic storage` part

Comment: You should use arrow functions in the uploadImage() function

Comment: Have you looked at [https://stackoverflow.com/a/41352560/9901630](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41352560/9901630)

Comment: firebase.storage is deprecated, use gcloud.storage instead : https://stackoverflow.com/a/39848966/9941039

Comment: @nullptr.t  the uploading and storing online files process are working great. the problem here when I try to save the URL locally to reuse later

Comment: @RanikaNisal can you please explain how to use arrow functions in here ??

Comment: @MsuArven I think that `gcloud.storage` will help in uploading the image which is already working great. the problem comes when I try to save the URL locally

Comment: I see now - the problem is that you're trying to use ```storage.set('name', 'Max');``` which is a method of the ionic storage object, but you have the firebase.storage set as the storage object as well, try re-naming the firebase storage object to differentiate it between the ionic storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please use fat arrow function instead on anonymous one as the former does not create its own execution scope while the latter does and hence your 'this' starts to point at it:

```
uploadImage(img, numb) {
    const ref = firebase.database().ref('Uploads');
    const storage = firebase.storage();
    const pathReference = storage.ref('images/' + this.id + numb + '.jpg');
    const message = img;
    pathReference.putString(message, 'base64', { contentType: 'image/jpg' }).then(function (snapshot) {
      console.log('Uploaded a base64url string!');
      // see here replaced 'function()' with =>:
      pathReference.getDownloadURL().then((url)=>{
        console.log(url);
        console.log(typeof(url));
        if (numb === 1) {
          this.storage.set('image_1_url', url);
        }
        if (numb === 2) {
          this.storage.set('image_2_url', url);
        }
        if (numb === 3) {
          this.storage.set('image_3_url', url);
        }
      });
    });


  }
```